# The catch statement repeatedly executes

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a (re)try-catch block.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true){
    try {
        t = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number without any symbol(s)!");
    }
}
```

But the problem here is that the control again goes into the catch block ones it reaches there and never attempts to execute the try block before that.

Comment: Is it because the scanner buffer wasn't cleared?

Comment: Try printing `e.getMessage()` to see what the exception actually is, for starters.

Comment: The exception was thrown because the (String) input couldn't be parsed into a number

Comment: I have actually solved the error by using `new java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt()`, but was curious enough to know why the catch block was being executed repeatedly.

Comment: How does `new java.util.Scanner.nextInt()` work?

Comment: It works [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). What is it that is not clear, in particular?

Comment: Why does it scan the buffer without clearing it? Is there any way to explicitly tell it to clear the buffer/maybe move to the next line and then scan the input as it's fetched into the buffer?

Comment: What do you mean "clearing it"?

Comment: If you want to read by line use `nextLine()` and then parse the result.

Comment: `assert(it=="buffer");`

Comment: So can we be sure that the try block executes before coming to the catch block for other `n(>=0)` iterations?

Comment: Like can we say that  `sc` is scanning the same line in the buffer without taking any input from the user?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it...

```
/*java.util.*/Scanner sc = new /*java.util.*/Scanner(System.in);

while(true)
{
  if(sc.hasNextInt()){ t=sc.nextInt(); break;}
  System.out.println("Please enter a whole number integer (between -2,147,483,649 and 2,147,483,648) without any symbol(s)!");
  sc.nextLine(); // hasNextInt() only scans the current line in the buffer
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should really learn to properly format your code and to properly use `import`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah sure. This is the only line in my code where I explicitly refer to the Scanner class. I mean I do know most of the programmers use it only explicitly refer to it only once in order to take input from the command line (System.in)